# How to authenticate otp entered by user from browser in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am working on OTP signin rails application.I have used active model otp gem for generating the otp.The gem creates otp_secret_key column to store otp. The application sends the OTP via mail to user.Then the user should enter email and correct otp to login (session should get created).I am stuck on the part of creating session.The code for session is as follows:

```
     def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])
        otp = params[:session][:otp_code]
        if user.authenticate_otp(otp)
           session[:user_id] = user.id
           flash[:success] = 'Successfully logged in'
           redirect_to welcome_home_path
        else
           flash.now[:danger] = 'Something wrong with your login information!'
        end
    end
```

The parameters present in params hash after submitting the form are:

```
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "session"=>{"email"=>"test23@example.com", "otp_code"=>"8496"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
```

But the on the browser it get stucks on the same page and in the terminal it shows tha `No template found for SessionsController#create, rendering head :no_content`
But I want to redirect it to welcome/home path if the values entered are correct.

How to do that?

P.S: I have user table with user_id,user_email and otp_secret_key column
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have this create method in SessionsController right? Also check if you have added all the routes in routes.rb

Comment: Yes, this is in session Controller and all the routes mentioned in  this method are working.If I simply write the code as `user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])    if user.present? redirect_to welcome_home_path' it goes to that path. I am having trouble with taking otp from browser and checking it from the database

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Have you checked what does params[:session][:otp_code] return?

Comment: I tried printing it like this 'puts params[:session][:otp_code]' to check what it returns, it throws error that `can't covert symbol to integer`

Comment: So now you now where the problem lies. It might be because you are using :otp_code but in your params its "otp_code". I am not sure if that's the exact issue. Go through this link to read more about it https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

Comment: I did this `value1 = params[:session][:otp_code]` and p[rinted out the `value`'. It gives the otp value entered.So it's returning correct value, so why the authenticate method is not working?

Comment: This is strange. I have used acttive_model_otp gem in multiple project and it works quite well. Also your code looks fine to me. What does user.authenticate_otp(otp) return? Also can you please share the schema for User model?

Comment: `user.authenticate_otp(otp)` is returning false. And my user model is as:   <pre>                                                                                 class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_time_password column_name: :otp_secret_key, length: 4
end
</pre>

Comment: The otp is now getting authenticated. Thankyou.

Comment: what was the exact issue?

Comment: I am not sure but I think since in active otp gem, the otp is by default valid only for 30 secs, trying to authenticate it after 30s was showing the error

Comment: Yes by default is 30 sec. You can increase it by using drift param.

Comment: Yes got it.Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in active otp gem, the otp for a specific user is valid only for 30 seconds. Due to this, if I authenticated the user immediately it was working. However after 30 seconds it was showing as 'invalid login information'. 
So I used the `drift:` to increase the otp validity time.